# KnockoutJS: fill out div after data load

Tags: knockout.js

I am new to Knockoutjs, and I need some help to properly bind the data.

I want knockoutjs to fill out each div after AJAX call completes and the data from server looks like following:

```
{
    name: 'michael',
    phone: '123456789',
    friends:
    [
        { sex: 'male', region: 'europe' },
        { sex: 'female', region: 'america' },
        { sex: 'male', region: 'asia' }
    ]
}
```

FYI, I want to bind above data WITHOUT using foreach to iterate and fill out 'friends' above. Instead, for some reason, I want to bind the data manually on each div, eg)

```
<div data-bind: friends[0].sex>...
<div data-bind: friends[1].sex>...
<div data-bind: friends[2].sex>...
```

Here's my JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VAcQB/

And it currently has error saying like:

```
Uncaught Error: Unable to parse bindings.
Message: TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined;
Bindings value: text: data.friends[0].sex
```

I think it's because it does not understand the binded data because the data is not available yet when the page loads.

Can someone please help to solve the issue? Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: *"...for some reason, I want to bind the data manually..."* - would you explain what's better in doing this manually?

Answer (score 0):

You should check that `data` is not null. The best way to do this is to use with binding:

```
<div data-bind="with: data">
 ... Your content
</div>
```

Here is working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VAcQB/2/

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I updated my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/VAcQB/1/ accordingly but I can't still get it working. Can you tell what's missing?

Comment: Sorry my initial answer was wrong... I missed that friends is not observable array. See updated answers.

Comment: It looks great. Thank you so much. I have one additional question. Is there anyway I can apply some kind of text formatting, for example, make text data to uppercase and etc... for example, calling function like <div data-bind="text: MyMethod(friends[0].sex)" ...>

Comment: You can write custom binding for this, here is an example - http://jsfiddle.net/VAcQB/3/